# Error passing DOMDocument through functions

Tags: php, xpath

Im writing a web crawler in PHP and I wrote a re-usable xPath evaluator.The function is:

```
function xPathEvalSingle($soruce, $xpathExpression) {
        $resultsFromXpath = $source->evaluate($xPathExpression)->item(0)->textContent;
        return $resultsFromXpath;
    }
```

I create a new DOMXPath object and load from a valid HTML page:

```
$page = $this->getPageHtml($newCrawlUrl);
$source = new DOMXPath($page);
```

Then call the function:

```
xPathEvalSingle($soruce, $xpathExpression) = Fatal error: Call to a member function evaluate() on a non-object
```

However, when I do it without a function, I get what I want

```
$resultsFromXpath = $source->evaluate($xPathExpression)->item(0)->textContent = What I want
```

How would I properly pass the DOMXPath to the function to make it work?

Comment: Very strange! The misspelled parameter name `$soruce` in your function has nothing to do with it, has it?

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: There appears to be different casing in the second parameter. In the function call it is 'xpath', but in the body of the function, its called as 'xPath' (capital letter P).

Answer (score 1):

Increase you error reporting level to include notices. You have the same variable typo `$soruce` in the declaration and the call of the function.

That means in the call an undefined variable is used.

Example:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $source = 42;
  print($soruce);
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: soruce in /tmp/... on line 4
```

Inside the function the argument is not used, but an unknown variable $source.

Example:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  function foo($soruce) {
    print($source);
  }

  foo(42);
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: source in /tmp/... on line 5
```